# Ruby lambda literal syntax

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have a doubt on the lambda literal syntax corresponding to that (more classic) lambda syntax:

```
lambda { |foo| }
```

Is the following correct?

```
->(foo) {}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's correct since Ruby 1.9.x.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is correct. More information about that in the official documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Procs